# GCC ARM : vtable not initialized

Tags: linker, arm, vtable

I'm using arm-none-eabi-g++ to compile for an ARM Cortex M microcontroller. My code statically instantiates some modules, initialize them, and execute them sequentially in a loop. Each module (`ModuleFoo`, `ModuleBar`...) is a class which herits from a common `Module` class. The `Module` class defines two virtual functions, `init()` and `exec()`, which are implemented in every derived module. There are no explicit constructors, neither in the base nor the derived classes. Finally, I have a Context struct which is passed around and contains a list of pointers to the modules (`Module* modules[]`).

I had the following code which worked :

```
int main() {
    ModuleFoo foo;
    ModuleBar bar;
    Context context;
    const int N_MODULES = 2;
    context.modules[0] = &foo; // Indexes are actually an enum but I stripped it to make it shorter
    context.modules[1] = &bar;

    for (int i = 0; i < N_MODULES; i++) {
        context.modules[i]->init(context);
    }

    while (1) {
        for (int i = 0; i < N_MODULES; i++) {
            context.modules[i]->exec(context);
        }
    }
}
```

So far, so good (at least I think so, in any case it worked).

Now, I want to make the system more maintainable by moving all the code related to "which modules are used in a particular configuration" to a separate `config.cpp`/`config.h` file :

`config.cpp` :

```
ModuleFoo foo;
ModuleBar bar;

void initContext(Context& context) {
    context.nModules = 2;
    context.modules[0] = &foo;
    context.modules[1] = &bar;
}
```

`main.cpp` :

```
#include "config.h"

int main() {
    Context context;
    initContext(context);

    for (int i = 0; i < context.nModules; i++) {
        context.modules[i]->init(context);
    }

    while (1) {
        for (int i = 0; i < context.nModules; i++) {
            context.modules[i]->exec(context);
        }
    }
}
```

The problem appears when `init()` is called on the first module (the MCU HardFaults). This is because, according to GDB, the vtable pointer is not initialized :

```
(gdb) p foo
$1 = {
  <Module> = {
    _vptr.Module = 0x0 <__isr_vector>, 
    _enabled = false
  },
```

I rolled back with Git to check, with the previous code structure the vtable pointer was correctly initialized. And according to the linker's map file and GDB, the vtable exists (at around the same address as before):

```
.rodata        0x0000000000008e14       0x2c ModuleFoo.o
               0x0000000000008e14                typeinfo name for ModuleFoo
               0x0000000000008e1c                typeinfo for ModuleFoo
               0x0000000000008e28                vtable for ModuleFoo
```

The pointer is simply not set. The only difference I see between the two versions is that in the first one the modules are instanciated on the stack, whereas on the second they are instanciated globally in the bss :

```
.bss           0x00000000200015fc      0x22c config.o
               0x00000000200015fc                foo
               0x000000002000164c                bar
```

Could this be the problem?

In any case, thanks for taking the time to read this far!

**EDIT : ** 
The problem was coming from the startup code and the linker script. I used the sample files provided with Atmel's ARM GCC toolchain, which seem to be poorely written and, most importantly, didn't call `__libc_init_array()` (which is used to call global constructors). I switched to using the startup/linker script from ASF, and it works way better. Thanks @FreddieChopin !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Show us the startup code you are using. Most likely you did not enable global constructors, which can be done by calling `__libc_init_array()` function. You can test this theory, by manually calling this function at the beginning of `main()` - it should work fine then. If it does, then you should add that function to your startup code (`Reset_Handler`).

Quick test:

```
int main() {
    extern "C" void __libc_init_array();
    __libc_init_array();
    // rest of your code...
```

To do it properly, find the place where your startup code calls main() (usually sth like `ldr rX, =main` and `blx rX` or maybe directly as `bl main`) and right before that do exactly the same but with `__libc_init_array` instead of `main`.

Comment: I'm using the ASM startup code provided by the manufacturer, it might be a bit too lengthy to post it here but as far as I can see it doesn't do that, so you are probably right. I have no idea how to "enable global constructors" however, and I don't know which header to include to get access to __libc_init_array :
"error: '__libc_init_array' was not declared in this scope"

Comment: Thanks. It compiles (I had to move the prorotype outside the main however) but it doesn't run. Here is the backtrace, which is strange because it doesn't start with main()... ?
#0  UsageFault_Handler () at ./startup_ARMCM4.S:235
#1  <signal handler called>
#2  0x00008d92 in typeinfo name for Module ()
#3  0x00008b64 in __libc_init_array ()
#4  0x200004b0 in _impure_ptr ()
Backtrace stopped: previous frame identical to this frame (corrupt stack?)

Comment: @Foaly hmm, strange... Generally for this function to work, your linker script has to provide several symbols, but I guess that they must be present, otherwise the linking would fail. But it's worth checking for things like: `__preinit_array_start`, `__preinit_array_end`, `__init_array_start` and `__init_array_end`. Maybe you could upload your project somewhere?

Comment: @Foaly - any chance you have `-nostartfiles` flag added for linking? It would prevent this whole thing from working.

Comment: Yes those symbols are defined in the linker script. I can't upload the whole project but here is the script in question : [http://pastebin.com/0a5KXtmT](http://pastebin.com/0a5KXtmT). There is mention of constructors, but I don't understand it well enough to see if there is a problem there. The `-nostartfiles` is not present, here are the linker flags : `--specs=nano.specs --specs=nosys.specs $(LDSCRIPTS) -Wl,--gc-sections $(MAP)`. I'm currently trying to disassemble `__libc_init_array` and step through it in GDB, maybe I'll understand what goes wrong. Thanks for your time!

Comment: @Foaly I highly recommend you not to use this stupid script which places init arrays in RAM... `__libc_init_array()` just executes functions stored between `__init_array_start` and `...end` - https://sourceware.org/git/gitweb.cgi?p=newlib-cygwin.git;a=blob;f=newlib/libc/misc/init.c;h=c85d6020fce96219872be3d8b245858300d54346;hb=HEAD

Comment: Ha thanks for the source that's way better, I only had the compiled version in my arm-none-eabi-gcc distribution and I failed finding it on google. This is the script provided by Atmel. Do you know how I could improve it? (I'm not even sure I understand why it is bad).

Comment: By the way, here is the startup code : [http://pastebin.com/kpRWRALi](http://pastebin.com/kpRWRALi)

Comment: @Foaly whether or not this would work depends on the exact compilation flags you pass for this startup file.

Comment: @Foaly Your linker script may not work with this startup, and this startup is not useful for any particular chip, as it does not have other chip vectors. The problem is that this pair is not "matched" and it probably does _NOT_ initialize .data section, while the stupid script places these init arrays there, so you end up jumping to random addresses and executing random instructions. What microcontroller do you have? You can find a shell script that generates linker scripts in my C++ RTOS project - http://distortos.org/ There's also a matching startup and some vector tables for different chips

Comment: According to the map file, there is nothing in the init and preinit arrays, so that might be a problem as well (they all start and end at the same address : 0x200004b0). The microcontroller is an ATSAM4L from Atmel. I'll check if they have updated their startup code and linker script since I've downloaded them, and otherwise I'll try your script.

Comment: Here are the flags : `-mthumb -mcpu=cortex-m4 -D__STARTUP_CLEAR_BSS -D__NO_SYSTEM_INIT -D__START=main -std=c++11 -Wall -Og -g`. I had a doubt about NO_SYSTEM_INIT but it only calls a `SystemInit` which is not defined, and I guess this is intended to be defined along the main.

Comment: You can reduce your problem to a much smaller one - create a project with one class with constructor (in separate source file), have this as a global object and verify with your debugger whether this constructor gets executed. It should - via `__libc_init_array()`.

Comment: So I checked where I found these files in the first place and they are actually provided with the toolchain as "samples". I looked further and found in the Atmel Software Framework (independant from the toolchain) some other code that look better (the init arrays are in the .text section, which should be better if I understood correctly). Here they are : [flash.ld](http://pastebin.com/Xt8B5X19), [sram.ld](http://pastebin.com/b3uchY4p), [startup_sam4l.c](http://pastebin.com/QUAYWDzQ). What do you think?

Comment: @Foaly - much better. They also have `KEEP(...)` for the arrays in the linker script, which might have been the culprit. The startup calls `__libc_init_array()` so you don't have to do that manually. Try the "flash.ld" with this startup and you'll see - there should definitely be "strange" functions used for construction of global objects, sth like `_GLOBAL__sub_I__...`.

Comment: Woot, it works! I had to copy a lot of stuff to follow all the #include and fiddle with the makefile, so now I have a lot of cleanup to do to keep only what's necessary. But the basis is here, and that will make the whole cleaner. This problem went way deeper than I thought... Anyway, thanks a lot for your help, I would have never found the answer alone and I learned a lot in the process!