# how to fix wrong GCC ARM startup code pointer to initialized and zero variables?

Tags: gcc, arm, startup

[skip to UPDATE2 and save some time :-)]
I use ARM Cortex-M4, with CMSIS 5-5.7.0 and FreeRTOS, compiling using GCC for ARM (10_2021.10)

My variables are not initialized as they should.
My startup code is pretty simple, the entry point is the reset handler (CMSIS declared startup_ARMCM4.s as deprecated and recommend using the C code startup code so this is what I do).

Here is my code:

```
__attribute__((__noreturn__)) void Reset_Handler(void)
{
  DataInit();
  SystemInit();                             /* CMSIS System Initialization */
  main();
}

static void DataInit(void)
{
    typedef struct {
      uint32_t const* src;
      uint32_t* dest;
      uint32_t  wlen;
    } __copy_table_t;

    typedef struct {
      uint32_t* dest;
      uint32_t  wlen;
    } __zero_table_t;

    extern const __copy_table_t __copy_table_start__;
    extern const __copy_table_t __copy_table_end__;
    extern const __zero_table_t __zero_table_start__;
    extern const __zero_table_t __zero_table_end__;

    for (__copy_table_t const* pTable = &__copy_table_start__; pTable < &__copy_table_end__; ++pTable) {
      for(uint32_t i=0u; i<pTable->wlen; ++i) {
        pTable->dest[i] = pTable->src[i];
      }
    }

    for (__zero_table_t const* pTable = &__zero_table_start__; pTable < &__zero_table_end__; ++pTable) {
      for(uint32_t i=0u; i<pTable->wlen; ++i) {
        pTable->dest[i] = 0u;
      }
    }

}
```

`__copy_table_start__, __copy_table_end__` etc. have the wrong values an so no data is copied to the appropriate place in RAM.

I tried adding __libc_init_array() before DataInit(), as suggested [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42274271/gcc-arm-vtable-not-initialized), and remove the nostartfiles flag from the linker, but at some point __libc_init_array() jumps to an illegal address and I get a HardFault interrupt.

Is there a different method to fix it? maybe one where I can use the nostartfiles flag?

UPDATE:
Looking at the memory, where `__copy_table_start__` is located, I see the data there is valid (even without the use of __libc_init_array()). It seems that pTable doesn't get the correct value.
I tried using `__data_start__, __data_end__, __bss_start__, __bss_end__ and __etext` instead of the above variables, in the linker file it is said they can be used in code without definition, but they cannot (maybe that's a clue?). In any case they didn't work either.

UPDATE2:
found the actual problem
all struct members get the same value (modifying one changes all others), it happens with every struct. I have no idea how this is possible. In other words the value of `__copy_table_start__.src` is, for example, 0x14651234, `__copy_table_start__.dest` is 0x00100000, and `__copy_table_start__.wlen` is 0x0365. When looking at pTable all members are 0x14651234.

Comment: I found the answer, and detail it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71062162/how-it-is-that-pointer-to-struct-shows-the-wrong-values/71065744#71065744)