# how it is that pointer to struct shows the wrong values?

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I use ARM-M4 with GCC for ARM (10_2021.10)
I have a problem where a pointer to struct displays the wrong values.

`__copy_table_start__` is define in the linker file, I see it's location in the map file and this is how I found it's true value (and the values make sense, they are correct)

Here is my code

```
#pragma GCC optimize("O0")
static void DataInit(void)
{
    typedef struct {
      uint32_t const* src;
      uint32_t* dest;
      uint32_t  wlen;
    } __copy_table_t;

    extern const __copy_table_t __copy_table_start__;
    extern const __copy_table_t __copy_table_end__;
    extern const __zero_table_t __zero_table_start__;
    extern const __zero_table_t __zero_table_end__;

    static volatile __copy_table_t const* pTable;
    
    pTable = &__copy_table_start__;

    for (; pTable < &__copy_table_end__; ++pTable) {
      for(uint32_t i=0u; i<pTable->wlen; ++i) {
        pTable->dest[i] = pTable->src[i];
      }
    }
}
```

And what I see in the debugger, right after `pTable = &__copy_table_start__;` is that:

```
__copy_table_start__.src = 0x14A0D380
__copy_table_start__.dest = 0x00100000
__copy_table_start__.wlen = 0x38A

pTable->src = 0x14A0D380
pTable->dest = 0x14A0D380
pTable->wlen = 0x14A0D380
```

How can that be?

UPDATE:
I did another experiment, I created another struct variable and a pointer to that variable and get the same results. first time I see this kind of behavior.

```
const __copy_table_t mine = {(uint32_t const*)0x12345678, (uint32_t *)0x00004545, 0x89890000};

static volatile __copy_table_t const* my_ptr;
my_ptr = &mine;
```

The result is that `my_ptr->src = my_ptr->dest = my_ptr->wlen = 0x12345678`

Comment: Your code isn't complete, but it seems very unlikely to be standards compliant. For the pointer arithmetic to be valid, the `__copy_table_start__` and `__copy_table_end__` must be part of the same array, but I don't think that's possible as written. "And what I see is that" is confusing because exactly what value is `pTable` holding at that point? After the loop, it'll be equal to `&__copy_table_end__` but you're comparing its contents to `__copy_table_start__`. Can you include a complete but minimal reproduction, and say exactly what's wrong?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. The code is from ARM's CMSIS startup code. I modified it (changed to static volatile) to enable inspecting the variable during debug.
I put here only part of the function for simplicity, the next was zeroing .bss using a different table and there I see the same problem.
what do you mean " must be part of the same array" one is the start table, and in case you have multple data sections you will have more tables where `__copy_table_end__` points to the end. I don't see the problem.

Comment: As I only have one data section and dest=src in the pTable pointer nothing happens, it doesn't loop at all.

Comment: Please include a complete example, including the actual code you're using to view the contents of `*my_ptr`.

Comment: It might be neater to declare `__copy_table_start__`, etc. as arrays. E.g. `extern const __copy_table_t __copy_table_start__[];` `extern const __copy_table_t __copy_table_end__[];`. Then `for (pTable = __copy_table_start__; pTable < __copy_table_end__; ++pTable)`.

Comment: This is the complete code. `__copy_table_start__` etc. are defined by the compiler not myself.
I see the values in debug in the debugger (the awful Keil)

Comment: Hm, I have difficulties to understand your issue. Are you saying A) that the simulator of Keil's IDE shows the wrong values, or B) that the debugger of Keil's IDE shows the wrong values as it accesses the _real_ variable of your existing target, or C) your running program in the existing target reads these values?

Comment: Option B is the one

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the problem is with Keil (the IDE).
It displays the wrong values.

When I created 3 new parameters and loaded the data to them:

```
my_src = (uint32_t)pTable->src;
my_dest = (uint32_t)pTable->dest;
my_len = (uint32_t)pTable->wlen;
```

Those parameters got the correct values.
What threw me off was that doing a single step in debug skipped the entire for loop (the first one), as if the internal for loop didn't do anything. It actually did what it was supposed to do, but one parameter that was supposed to be reset after that didn't update in the IDE.